# Sorting groups in solr by top result in each group

Tags: solr, solr6

Is there a way to sort groups in solr based on just the top result in the group and not all the members? For example, I'm grouping product variants by model, and sorting each group by the number of resellers. This gives me the product variant with the most resellers at the top of each group. Next I'm applying a low price sort to the entire result set. Currently all the groups are being ordered by the lowest price within the group, rather than the lowest price of the top product.

For faceting you can do group.truncate=true if you are just concerned with the top result, but I don't see anything similar for sorting.

Is this possible or will I just have to do my own sorting in custom request handler.